# How do I do collision between two RectangleShapes in SFML 2.5.0? (C++)

Tags: c++, sfml

So I'm relatively new to coding in SFML, so apologies if I made some newbie mistake. My project is Space Invaders in SFML. When I was working on the shooting, a problem arose. How do I do collision? I was familiar with shape.getGlobalBounds().intersect(), and it worked on previous projects. It didn't work. So I tried simplifying it. I used RectangleShape for both the enemy shape, and the bullet shape.

Here is the actual for loop, for the collision:

```
for (int y = 0; y <= 2; ++y) {
    for (int x = 0; x <= 6; ++x) {
        if (shootShape.getPosition().x < e.aliensX[x] && shootShape.getPosition().x > e.aliensX[x] + 15 ||
            shootShape.getPosition().y < e.aliensY[y] && shootShape.getPosition().y > e.aliensY[y] + 15) {
            e.aliensX[x] = -10;
            e.aliensY[y] = -10;
            shooting = false;
            reload = false;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the shooting function:

```
void Player::shoot() {
    if (reload) {
        shootX = posX + 5;
        shootY = posY - 50;
        shootShape.setPosition(shootX, shootY);
        shooting = true;
        reload = false;
    }
    if (shooting) {
        shootY -= 150 * 2 * deltaTime;
        shootShape.setPosition(shootX, shootY);
    }
}
```

And this is how I draw the enemies (I don't know how to create multiple enemies):

```
void Enemy::drawAliens() {
    for (int j = 0; j <= arraySizeY; ++j) {
        for (int i = 0; i <= arraySizeX; ++i) {
            actualShape.setPosition(aliensX[i], aliensY[j]);
            if (aliensY[i] <= p.shootY && aliensY[i] >= p.shootY) {
                aliensX[i] = -10;
                aliensY[i] = -10;
            }
            else {
                win.draw(actualShape);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Explanation behind some of the variables:
aliensX is an array which contains the different x positions for the enemies.
aliensY is an array which contains the different y positions for the enemies.
shooting is a bool variable, which is true when the bullet is travelling.
reload is whether you can shoot.

EDIT:
Intersect will not work because of the way I created my enemies. They are all in ONE shape. I need it to work with specific coordinates, because I don't know a better way to create multiple enemies all at once. If there is a way to do that, advice would be appreciated!

Comment: `e.aliensX[x]` contains the x coordinate of all aliens in that line? If one alien moves, all aliens move?

Comment: @ThomasSablik Yes, I'm making a copy of Space Invaders, and that's how the game moves the aliens.

Comment: I don't understand your question. What do you want and where is your problem? You have a function to detect collisions?

Comment: Yes, but it isn't working. That's the problem.

Comment: Because your if statement is never true. You have `shootShape.getPosition().x < e.aliensX[x] && shootShape.getPosition().x > e.aliensX[x] + 15`. Your shootShape x position can never be smaller than some aX and bigger than aX + 15 at the same time. That's impossible. The same for y position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's rather easy, if you rely on SFML's templated `sf::Rect` class. Just retrieve the rectangle for both objects as global boundaries and try to intersect them:

```
const bool collides = firstDrawable.getGlobalBounds().intersect(secondDrawable.getGlobalBounds());`
```

Same can be done with a small temporary rectangle you can fill with dynamic values not directly associated with a `sf::Drawable`:

```
const sf::FloatRect bullet(x - width / 2, y - height / 2, width, height);
const bool collides = firstDrawable.getGlobalBounds().intersect(bullet);`
```

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't work.. Let me try again for good measure and let you know.

Comment: Here is what I did: hit = e.actualShape.getGlobalBounds().intersects(shootShape.getGlobalBounds()); (It didn't work!)

Comment: @Zayyan That should work, maybe your coordinates were off?

Comment: I realized my mistake! I don't have individual shapes, so intersect wouldn't work! Is there a way to do this with specific values?

Comment: @Zayyan You can just create temporary rectangles for your bullets (or store them) and use those instead. Adding a quick snippet..

Answer (score 0):

Your if statement is never true. You have

```
shootShape.getPosition().x < e.aliensX[x] && shootShape.getPosition().x > e.aliensX[x] + 15.
```

Your `shootShape.getPosition().x` can never be smaller than `e.aliensX[x]` and bigger than `e.aliensX[x] + 15` at the same time. That's impossible. The same for y position. Change your if statement to

```
for (int y = 0; y <= 2; ++y) {
  for (int x = 0; x <= 6; ++x) {
    if (shootShape.getPosition().x > e.aliensX[x] && shootShape.getPosition().x < e.aliensX[x] + 15 ||
        shootShape.getPosition().y > e.aliensY[y] && shootShape.getPosition().y < e.aliensY[y] + 15) {
      e.aliensX[x] = -10;
      e.aliensY[y] = -10;
      shooting = false;
      reload = false;
    }
  }
}
```